# count observations by group and keep only those belonging to at least two groups

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id    group
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     A
3     A
3     B
```

I would like to create a variable that counts how many groups each individual belongs to and based on that I want to keep in the data frame only those individuals with more than one group. In this case id 2 would be dropped. I know I can count by doing

```
table(data$group)
```

but I haven't been able to use this to remove those with only one group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the OP needs to keep only 'id' where the `length` of `unique` elements in 'group' is greater than 1, we could use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'ID', we return the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) `if` the `length` of `unique` elements in 'group' is greater than 1. (`uniqueN` is a convenient wrapper of `length(unique(.`)

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(data)[,if(uniqueN(group)>1) .SD , by = id]
 #   id group
 #1:  1     A
 #2:  1     B
 #3:  1     C
 #4:  3     A
 #5:  3     B
```

NOTE: If this is based on only `length`, we replace the `uniqueN(group)>1` by `length(group)>1`

---

It is not entirely clear whether we can subset using just 'id' column or need the `length(unique` in 'group' column.  If we are using only 'id', one option is `duplicated`

```
data[duplicated(data$id)|duplicated(data$id, fromLast=TRUE),]
#  id group
#1  1     A
#2  1     B
#3  1     C
#5  3     A
#6  3     B
```

Comment: I get the following error: could not find function "uniqueN". I guess it is because after install.packages("data.table") I get data.table 1.9.4 or I need to call another library?

Comment: @user2246905 I am using the devel version.  But you can replace with `length(unique(group))>1`

Comment: @user2246905 I have a doubt.  Suppose if you have an 'id' 1 with 3 elements and all the group element is 'A'.  Do you remove that?

Answer (score 3):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(length(group) > 1)
```

Suggested by @Frank

Alternatively, if you want to check for unique(group) rather than length(group):

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(group) > 1)
```

Comment: And to extend it to the case that akrun is addressing, `n_distinct(group)>1`

Answer (score 3):

```
df[df$id %in% names(which(table(df$id) > 1)),]
#  id group
#1  1     A
#2  1     B
#3  1     C
#5  3     A
#6  3     B
```

Using your `table` approach, you can check which ids appear more than once. The assumption is that an id appears once per group.

**Update**

```
df[df$id %in% names(which(rowSums(!!(table(df$id, df$group))) > 1)),]
```

I added a reference to the second column just in case multiple values appear for the same id.