# Keep only observations from consecutive quarters

Tags: r

I'm currently looking at bank data for 9 consecutive quarters. I now want to only keep those banks for which I have data from all 9 quarters. Each bank has a unique certification ID. How can I filter using the ID and only keep banks with 9 consecutive observations?

Maybe a way to do this is to count how often a certification ID (cert) shows up and keep only the ones with 9 observations? So this is what I tried:

```
df <- (...)   
a = rle(sort(df$cert))    
b = data.frame(id=a$values, n=a$lengths)   
c = subset(b, n==9)
```

I'm unsure if this is correct because I'm trying to reproduce the results of a research paper but the numbers don't match anymore after this step.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as it will increase the likelihood of your question receiving an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612212/count-observations-by-group-and-keep-only-those-belonging-to-at-least-two-groups/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be `n_distinct` with `group_by`,  Grouped by 'id', check whether the number of distinct elements in 'qtr' is 9 and `filter` those 'id's rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(qtr) ==9)
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually confirmed my results. Unfortunately it is still not the same as in the paper I'm trying to reproduce but at least that means the mismatch must occur somewhere else.

Comment: @carical  It is better to provide a small reproducible example;   In that case, it would become easier

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-data.frame(id=rep(1:4,times=9),
               qtr=rep(1:9,each=4))

df%>%
  filter(id %in% (df%>%
                 count(id)%>%
                  filter(n>8)%>%.$id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generated an example. Use `rowSums` and `!is.na` to count the number of rows with values for all 9 columns.

```
a[rowSums(!is.na(a))==9,]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25
[2,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27
```

The data used.

```
a <- matrix(1:27, ncol=9, nrow=3)
a[2,2] <- NA
a

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    4    7   10   13   16   19   22   25
[2,]    2   NA    8   11   14   17   20   23   26
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27
```